# Pass Property and get class

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

This might be a trivial question but I am drawing a blank here and can't seem to find the answer online.

Basically, I am trying to create a method that takes 2 properties that are part of an `INotifyPropertyChanged` class as parameters (the actual properties to be used in reflection, not the property values), and keep them "in sync" like a binding.

### Example

I have a class called `Student` with a property called `int SemesterScore`. I have another class called `Semester` with a property called `int Score`. Both of the classes implement `IPropertyNotifyChanged`.

Now, let's just assume for a moment that we can't extend any of the classes (as in my real-life scenario) and I may have multiple times in different classes I want to use this.

Basically, I want to be able to call a method in one of my classes that "links" the two properties together.. aka if one of them changes it will auto-update the other.

In non-working code, this is the basic concept:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _semesterScore;
    public  int SemeseterScore
    {
        get { return _semesterScore; }
        set { [ set property stuff with property changed] }
    }
}

public class Semester: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _score;
    public  int Score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        set { [ set property stuff with property changed] }
    }
}

public class Entry
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        Semester semester = new Semester();

        AttachProperties(student.SemesterScore, semester.Score); // This obviously won't work, but this is where I pass the properties in

        semester.Score = 7;
        Console.WriteLine(student.SemesterScore); // Output will be 7
    }

    public static void AttachProperties([sometype] prop1, [sometype] prop2)
    {
        // Sudo code
        prop1.classInstance.PropertyChanged += (pe)
        {
            if (pe.Property == prop1.Name)
                prop2.Value = prop1.Value;
        }

        prop2.classInstance.PropertyChanged += (pe)
        {
            if (pe.Property == prop2.Name)
                prop1.Value = prop2.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I know some workarounds (aka pass the INotifyPropertyChanged classes and the property names, then do some reflection to get that to work), but the question of passing property instances around (and doing stuff with it) has come up a few times in my coding career.

Comment: Do you need to dynamicly choose which property to keep in sync, or will it always be the same one every time. Basically what I am asking is can you make a class that works only for linking the score between `Student` and `Semester` or do you need something that is more flexible and would work with any two classes that implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah the question is to make it more flexible so I can apply it to any property in any class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so I don't manually have to subscribe to the events. This is going to be reused multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know some workarounds (aka pass the INotifyPropertyChanged classes and the property names, then do some reflection to get that to work), but the question of passing property instances around (and doing stuff with it) has come up a few times in my coding career.

This is, ultimately, the way to do it. However, I think one key trick that you might not be aware of is Expression Trees. It is possible to create a function that takes an `Expression<Func<T>>` as an argument, and then delve into the Expression Tree to discover the `INotifyPropertyChanged` instance and the property that's given in the argument. Usage could look like this:

```
    AttachProperties(() => student.SemesterScore, () => semester.Score);
```

The arguments to `AttachProperties` in the example above would be `Expression`s with the following structure.

```
<LambdaExpression>            () => student.SemesterScore
  Body <MemberExpression>           student.SemesterScore
    Member <PropertyInfo>                   SemesterScore
    Expression <MemberExpression>   student
      Member <FieldInfo>            [closure class.]student
      Expression <ConstantExpression> [closure]
        Value                       [closure instance]
```

Notice that you're creating a closure by using `student` inside of the lambda expression, so to get the value of `student` you'll need to use reflection to get the value of the `[closure class].student` field. Getting the `SemesterScore` property is just a matter of casting the expressions correctly and getting the `.Body.Member` property from the passed-in lambda expression.

Comment: Actually, he does not need to use reflection to get the value, calling `prop1.Compile()` gives you a normal `Func<T>` you can call and get the result of. Now assigning the value to the property, that will likely require reflection (Or the passing in of a `Action<T>` to act as the setter)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: In order to subscribe to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event firing, he needs access to the instance of `student` at the time that the method is called.

Comment: `Student instance = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student>>(((MemberExpression)prop1.Body).Expression).Compile()()` :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yes, that's one way to do it. Seems a little heavy-handed to compile the expression when you're only going to invoke it once and throw it away, but the code is simpler, especially if you want to support more complicated expressions like `foo.Student.SemesterScore`.

Comment: I did end up going with your answer -- thanks for drawing out lambda expressions and how to use them (Although I did use @ScottChamberlain's instance compiliation -- there will be times I need to use advanced compiles)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to use an `Observable`, like @itay-podhacer suggested above.

But if you want to implement using just Reflection and `INotifyPropertyChanged` here is how you could do it.

First, lets get `SemesterScore` and `Student` both implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int semesterScore;

    public int SemesterScore
    {
        get { return semesterScore; }
        set
        {
            semesterScore = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Semester : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int score;

    public int Score
    {
        get { return score; }
        set
        {
            score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now lets tie the properties together, in your `AttachProperties` helper method. In order to do this, we will make the AttachProperties method take `Expression<Func<T,object>` arguments so that we avoid passing magic strings and can use Reflection to retrieve the properties names.

By the way, to run this in production you probably want to memoize that reflection code for performance.

```
private static void AttachProperties<T1,T2>(Expression<Func<T1, object>> property1, T1 instance1, Expression<Func<T2, object>> property2,  T2 instance2)
            where T1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
            where T2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    var p1 = property1.GetPropertyInfo();
    var p2 = property2.GetPropertyInfo();

        //A NULL or empty PropertyName in PropertyChangeEventArgs means that all properties changed
        //See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1

        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)instance1).PropertyChanged += (_, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == p1.Name || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName))
            {
                SyncProperties(p1, p2, instance1, instance2);
            }
        };

        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)instance2).PropertyChanged += (_, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == p2.Name || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName))
            {
                SyncProperties(p2, p1, instance2, instance1);
            }
        };
}

private static void SyncProperties(PropertyInfo sourceProperty, PropertyInfo targetProperty, object sourceInstance, object targetInstance)
{
    var sourceValue = sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceInstance);
    var targetValue = targetProperty.GetValue(targetInstance);

    if (!sourceValue.Equals(targetValue))
    {
        targetProperty.SetValue(targetInstance, sourceValue);
    }
}
```

And, finally, here is the Reflection code to retrieve the `PropertyInfo` from the arguments:

```
public static class ReflectionExtension
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = GetMemberExpression(expression);
        return (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
    }

    private static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<TModel, T>(Expression<Func<TModel, T>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = null;
        if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            var body = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
            memberExpression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", "expression");
        }

        return memberExpression;
    }
}
```

With all this in place, you can keep two properties in sync now:

```
public class PropertySyncTests
{
    public void Should_sync_properties()
    {
        var semester = new Semester();
        var student = new Student();
        AttachProperties(x => x.Score, semester, x => x.SemesterScore, student);
        semester.Score = 7;
        student.SemesterScore.ShouldBe(7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but [like I mentioned to Oliver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382410/c-sharp-pass-property-and-get-class?noredirect=1#comment64175618_38382800), your `if (e.PropertyName == p1.Name)` needs to be `if (e.PropertyName == p1.Name || String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName))` because a null or empty property name means all properties have been updated.

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain. I did not know that. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was hoping not to do -- aka extract out the class instance from the expression rather than having to pass the class instance as well (keeps it cleaner + neater). I did end up going with @striplingwarrior but used some help from your code (such as the reflection extensions).
Can you explain to me though why you are looking at the ExpressionType in your `GetMemberExpression` rather than just casting `((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member as PropertyInfo`?

Comment: @NolanBlew A boxed struct does not show up as a `MemberExpression`, it will show up as a `Convert` which wraps a `MemberExpression`. The check he is doing is unboxing the struct. If `Student` or `Semister` was a struct instead of a class it would use that 2nd block.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of the semester:

```
Student student = new Student();
Semester semester = new Semester();
semester.PropertyChanged += Semester_PropertyChanged;
```

Then assign the new score to the student

```
private void Semester_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    student.SemesterScore = semester.Score;
}
```

This will trigger the student's `PropertyChanged` event and also update his `SemesterScore` if the score changed.

Comment: I think the OP understands how to do this much, but he's trying to figure out a way to create a helper method that will shorten the syntax so he can call it like the `AttachProperties` method in his sample.

Comment: Your logic does not follow the rules of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, your if needs to be `if(e.PropertyName == nameof(Semester.Score) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName)) {` to follow the spec. A null or empty string passed in as the property name means all properties on the class have been updated and need to be refreshed.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I never encounterd this rule. Can you give a reference? The description of the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) does not mention it.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes it is on [PropertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.propertyname(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the Remarks section. *"An Empty value or null for the propertyName parameter indicates that all of the properties have changed.*"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Reactive UI Extensions](http://reactiveui.net/), it will give you the ability to "observe" a property for changes and then update (or do whatever you want) once such change occurs.

It will allow you to do something like this:

```
student
    .WhenAnyValue(item => item.SemeseterScore)
    .Subscribe(item => 
    {
        semester.Score = item.SemeseterScore
    });

semester
    .WhenAnyValue(item => item.Score)
    .Subscribe(item => 
    {
        item.SemeseterScore = semester.Score
    });
```

You might need to add an `Ignore` flag at your class and turn it on and off inside the `Subscribe` code, so you don't create an endless loop of updates between the two classes.

Comment: This is cool, but we currently aren't using Reactive UI for architectural reasons. If we ever do implement it this seems a lot nicer than using reflection

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I combined @StriplingWarrior and @Pedro's answers together to get my final result:

```
    public static void AttachProperties<T1, T2>(Expression<Func<T1>> property1, Expression<Func<T2>> property2)
    {
        var instance1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(((MemberExpression)property1.Body).Expression).Compile()();
        var iNotify1 = instance1 as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        var prop1 = GetPropertyInfo(property1);

        var instance2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(((MemberExpression)property2.Body).Expression).Compile()();
        var iNotify2 = instance2 as INotifyPropertyChanged;
        var prop2 = GetPropertyInfo(property2);

        AttachProperty(prop1, iNotify1, prop2, iNotify2);
        AttachProperty(prop2, iNotify2, prop1, iNotify1);
    }

    static void AttachProperty(
        PropertyInfo property1,
        INotifyPropertyChanged class1Instance,
        PropertyInfo property2,
        INotifyPropertyChanged class2Instance)
    {
        class2Instance.PropertyChanged += (_, propArgs) =>
        {
            if (propArgs.PropertyName == property2.Name || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propArgs.PropertyName))
            {
                var prop = property2.GetValue(class2Instance);
                property1.SetValue(class1Instance, prop);
            }
        };
    }

    static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T1>(Expression<Func<T1>> property)
    {
        MemberExpression expression = null;
        if (property.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            var body = (UnaryExpression)property.Body;
            expression = body.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else if (property.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            expression = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", nameof(property));
        }

        return expression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
```

This works correctly both in the example I gave and in my real-life project. Thanks!